# ReactiveUI: How to cancel an Observable from a ReactiveCommand?

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I have the following:

```
Compress = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ImagesCount, x => x > 0).ToCommand();
var process = Compress.RegisterAsync(ConvertImages);
var subscription = process.Subscribe(x => Images.Remove(x));

CancelConversion = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ImagesCount, x => x.IsBusy, (count, busy) => count > 0 && busy).ToCommand();
CancelConversion.RegisterAsyncAction();
```

Where `ConvertImages(object o)` is a private method of the ViewModel that, in turn, calls and returns the result of `ConvertImages(IEnumerable<ImageDto> images)` in a service class that resizes and compresses the images and returns an `IObservable<ImageDto>`.

Paul Betts suggests [here](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/581#issuecomment-42360452) to implement cancellation via the implementation of my `IObservable` e.g. using `Observable.create`, so can anyone provide an example of how to implement such Observable?

Also what is the RxUI™ way to signal this cancellation? Should I `subscription.Dispose()` in `CancelConversion.RegisterAsyncAction()`? Should I add `.TakeUntil(CancelConversion.Execution_Signaled)` to `var process`, how can I determine "CancelConversion.Execution_Signaled"?

Comment: I'm not understanding the signature of ConvertImages, is it really `IObservable<ImageDto> ConvertImages(IObservable<ImageDto> images)`?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the method signature it's `ConvertImages(IEnumerable<ImageDto> images)`, is there any issue if the type of the param were IObservable<>?

Comment: In that case, wouldn't the `x` in `process.Subscribe(x=>...` be an `IObservable<ImageDto>`?

Comment: I've corrected the question to reflect the actual chain of execution, there was one step missing, maybe that was why @PaulBetts was asking about the signature of the method, sorry for that.
Actually, @MojoFilter, because `ConvertImages(object o)` returns an `IObservable<ImageDto>` it will push `ImageDto`objects to the subscribers right? IntelliSense is showing those types on my VS.

Comment: @LucianoDelucchi You are totally right. I'm so used to using `RegisterAsyncTask` and `*Func` that it looked odd to me.

Comment: @MojoFilter Without the helping hand of the IDE is easy to lose focus :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fairly easy:

```
CancelConversion = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ImagesCount, x => x.IsBusy, (count, busy) => count > 0 && busy).ToCommand();

this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ImagesCount, x => x > 0).ToCommand();

var process = Compress.RegisterAsync(x => ConvertImages().TakeUntil(CancelConversion));
var subscription = process.Subscribe(x => Images.Remove(x));
```

Handling the actual cancellation (i.e. stopping whatever work that ConvertImages is really doing) depends on your implementation of ConvertImages.

Comment: "This is fairly easy" That's exactly how I thought it should be!
So `TakeUntil()` will `Dispose()` the subscription once it's finished right?
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @LucianoDelucchi Yep, you're correct - you usually don't have to manage disposables explicitly

Comment: Is line 3 needed at all?